# storing something if the statement is true

Tags: php, if-statement

This is a simple code I can't figure out

```
if(preg_match(  "/where/","where's my backpack") == true){
    echo "this is a match";
    // this is the part i cant figure out
    // how can I store it as == $match1
    // I tried $match1 == "this is a match"; but it didn't work   

}else{
    //$match1= " "; << this what I tried and didn't work
    //when I say echo match1 later, it displays this is a match even when its wrong
}
```

how can I store it as a variable or something for later. for example, if those two matches are true, store it as $match1 so that I can later say 'echo $match1' so that it displays "this is a match". if not just display a space.

the overall code is in php BTW

Answer (score 2):

`==` operator checks for equality, to store something you need to use `=`

```
$match1 = '';
if(preg_match("/where/", "where's my backpack"))
    $match1 = "this is a match";
else
    $match1 = " ";
echo $match1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it directly:

```
$match = preg_match("/where/","where's my backpack") === 1
```

Now you have a boolean value that you can use anywhere after this statement.

Note that I have replaced your `true` with `1` as that is what `preg_match` will return but either will work.

By the way, I realize that this is not exactly what you want but I find it easier to maintain and more reusable when I separate output texts from logic like this.